# How to make the ToolTip follow the mouse?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, tooltip, onmousemove

I want the ToolTip to follow my mouse moving over one control. For example, let's take a panel. When mouse location is inside the Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50) I want ToolTip to be visible and always on the right down of the mouse. When it's outside this rectangle, I want ToolTip to be invisible.

I tried to do this like that:

```
ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
int x, y;

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
      if ((x == e.X) && (y == e.Y) && (new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50).Contains(e.Location))
          toolTip.Show("some text", this, x + 10, y + 10);
      else
      {
          x = e.X;
          y = e.Y;
          toolTip.Hide(this);
      }
}
```

But there's a problem - when my toolTip shows up - it gets the focus and after that OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) doesn't work any more. I tried to get the focus to the panel in the end of that function, but it doesn't work. I also tried some tricks with OnMouseHover, but it was the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a ToolTip for that - if the Panel is drawn on, draw your own ToolTip; otherwise, use a Panel and respond to MouseMove events from both, but ignore `e.Location` and instead use `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position` and `PointToClient`.

Comment: I forgot about drawing. It works great, fast and no flicker at all! Thank you :)